# Errors while trying to cleanup HTML with DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm trying to get the HTML of a webpage and strip it of `<script>` tags. I can get the HTML (by using `cURL`), but I cannot strip the `<script>` tags using PHP's `DOMDocument`. Stripping the tags is just one thing I want to do with DOMDocument so I cannot use another solution (well I could use some other DOM parser I guess, but I just want to know how to fix it).

My code:

```
function clean_html(&$html, $targets = array('script'))
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html); // here I get the error

    foreach($targets as $target) {
        $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName($target);
        $length = $tags->length;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
          $tags->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild($tags->item(0));
        }
    }

    return $doc->saveHTML();
}

$html = get_html('http://www.google.nl'); // this gets the HTML using cURL.
clean_html($html);
```

The errors (lots of these +/- 20):

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 24 in C:...\code\views\index.phtml on line 22

The HTML I got from the cURL call:

http://pastebin.com/TrV99wAr

Is there a way to let DOMDocument fix the errors or at least let it parse the rest of the html?

Answer (score 2):

## Security first

For sanitization of HTML-Input there is only one tool out there which can protect you.
You always have to use this tool if it isn't data you yourself manage. (and even than, in case of someone getting your login-data, it may be better to use it).

**Always use HTMLPurifier:**

It may be resource-hungry, but everything else is like pointing a gun at your infrastructure.
http://htmlpurifier.org/

### I couldn't reproduce your error.

Therefore I **guess** it may be a bug which is version/platform specific. i tested on WinXP,Pro,x86,SP3/PHP5.3.3

Comment: `as pastebin usually is`. I don't get my HTML from pastebin. There is just a sample of the HTML I get to show the error :)

Comment: yeah my mistake, i already corrected it ^^ just too quick in looking at code/links *g*

Comment: also to add: 1) i don't know what htmlpurifier is using internally, and i'm looking deeper into your problem to see were the error was. may it help you to learn and somebody else who doesn't want to sanitize html ;)

Comment: okay, sorry to say, but if i paste your pastebin code into an .txt, copy&paste your code and replace `$html = get_html('http://www.google.nl');` with `$html = file_get_contents('google.nl.txt');` I don't get a single error. and i feel like a kiddy for so much copy&pasting ^^

Comment: It's not the part of getting the HTML which produces the error. But the part where `DOMDocument` tries to parse it :P And I use cURL :)

Comment: do you have any additional information which could help us narrow down that bug? does it reoccur if you don't curl but load from file?

Comment: @PeeHaa I know, and thats the problem, I used your whole script except one line, the one you said not making the problem. I made a gist to help you see. https://gist.github.com/1563560

Answer (score 0):

That error means you have a `&` in your HTML that is not an HTML entity. These should always be encoded as `&amp;`.

Comment: Well, obviously it is not my code (I don't own `google.nl`) :P How do I prevent getting those errors and let it parse the html?

Comment: Enable internal errors for libxml: `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);`